# How to remove duplicate empId record line, if empId is same for both arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove duplicate empId record line, if empId is same for both arrays. I tried below code, I can able to concatenate both arrays, but unable to duplicate if emplId is same. Could you please help me on this,

```js
var array1=[], array2 =[], array3=[]

array1 = [{"empid":"10043","empsalary":"10000","empaddress":"test1"},
    {"empid":"10044","empsalary":"20000","empaddress":"test2"},
    {"empid":"10045","empsalary":"30000","empaddress":"test3"},
    {"empid":"10046","empsalary":"40000","empaddress":"test4"},
    {"empid":"10047","empsalary":"50000","empaddress":"test5"},
]

array2 = [{"empid":"10043","empsalary":"10000","empaddress":"test1"},
    {"empid":"10044","empsalary":"20000","empaddress":"test2"},
    {"empid":"10048","empsalary":"30000","empaddress":"test3"},
    {"empid":"10049","empsalary":"40000","empaddress":"test4"},
    {"empid":"10041","empsalary":"50000","empaddress":"test5"},
]

array3 = [...new Set([...array1 ,...array2])]

console.log(JSON.stringify(array3));
```

Expected output:

```
[{"empid":"10043","empsalary":"10000","empaddress":"test1"},
    {"empid":"10044","empsalary":"20000","empaddress":"test2"},
    {"empid":"10048","empsalary":"30000","empaddress":"test3"},
    {"empid":"10049","empsalary":"40000","empaddress":"test4"},
    {"empid":"10045","empsalary":"30000","empaddress":"test3"},
    {"empid":"10046","empsalary":"40000","empaddress":"test4"},
    {"empid":"10047","empsalary":"50000","empaddress":"test5"}
    {"empid":"10041","empsalary":"50000","empaddress":"test5"}
]
```

Comment: use array filter instead or maybe array reduce .... either one will do

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an array that has all the employees from `array1` and `array2`. Then, it can be filtered using a set of employee-ids. If the id exists, ignore the item, else, take the item and add `item.empid` to the set of employee-ids.

```js
const empIdSet = new Set();
array3 = [...array1 ,...array2].filter((emp) => {
  if (empIdSet.has(emp.empid)) return false;

  empIdSet.add(emp.empid);
  return true;
});

console.log(array3);
```

You could shorten this to a one liner but it would either increase the time complexity or hamper the readability, or both.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out existing employees from array 1 `array2.filter(a2 => !array1.map(a1=>a1.empid).includes(a2.empid))`

```js
let array1 = [{"empid":"10043","empsalary":"10000","empaddress":"test1"},
    {"empid":"10044","empsalary":"20000","empaddress":"test2"},
    {"empid":"10045","empsalary":"30000","empaddress":"test3"},
    {"empid":"10046","empsalary":"40000","empaddress":"test4"},
    {"empid":"10047","empsalary":"50000","empaddress":"test5"},
]

let array2 = [{"empid":"10043","empsalary":"10000","empaddress":"test1"},
    {"empid":"10044","empsalary":"20000","empaddress":"test2"},
    {"empid":"10048","empsalary":"30000","empaddress":"test3"},
    {"empid":"10049","empsalary":"40000","empaddress":"test4"},
    {"empid":"10041","empsalary":"50000","empaddress":"test5"},
]

let array3 = [...array1, ...array2.filter(a2 => !array1.map(a1=>a1.empid).includes(a2.empid))];

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Set of array1 and array2 does not work as expected, reason being object references are different. To overcome this either use filter or reduce methods. Filter is shown in one of the answers. Here is the example of reduce -

```
const empidHash = new Set();
array3 = [...array1, ...array2]].reduce((filteredList, currentItem) => {
  if (!empidHash.has(currentItem.empid)) {
    empidHash.add(currentItem.empid);
    filteredList.push(currentItem);
  }
  return filteredList;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this process.

```
 array1.forEach((employee) => {
  this.check(employee, array3);
});
array2.forEach((employee) => {
  this.check(employee, array3);
});
```

here is the check function

```
check(employee, array3) {
let res = array3.some((empl) => empl.empid == employee.empid);
//console.log(employee, array3, res);
if (!res) array3.push(employee);}
```